# Kotlin, How to use the collection function to simplify this code

Tags: kotlin

I am using Kotlin for a project, I write this code can complete the requirement:

```
val rewards = ArrayList<Map<String, Int>>()
rangeExams
  .forEach { examAnswer ->
    var reward = hashMapOf("Score" to examAnswer.answerScore)
    var questionIds = examAnswer
      .answers
      .map { it.id }

    reward.put("NewQuestion", questionIds.size)
    rewards.add(reward)
  }
```

"rangeExams" is a list of collection.
I would like to combinate Kotlin Functions of Collection, 
to put elements of rangeExams into a map 
and put this map to a new list,
how can I simplify this code by Kotlin ?

ExamAnswer is a pojo:

```
class ExamAnswer (val id: String, val answerScore: Int, val answers:List<Answer>)
```

Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you add an item to the `rewards` for each element of `rangeExams`, the `.forEach { ... }` call can be transformed to [`.map { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html).

Also, you only use the result of `examAnswer.answers.map { it.id }` to get its size, so you can remove `.map { it.id }` and use the size of the original collection.

If you don't need to mutate the maps afterwards, you can replace `hashMapOf(...)` with `mapOf(...)`.

```
val rewards = rangeExams.map { 
    mapOf(
        "Score" to it.answerScore,
        "NewQuestion" to it.answers.size)
}
```

If you need to mutate the `rewards` list after it's created, add [`.toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) in the end.

Comment: Also you can replace "it" by (answerScore, answers) ->

Comment: Instead of calling `.toMutableList()` at the end, you can instead use `.mapTo(mutableListOf()) { ... }` to avoid allocating multiple collections.

Comment: @hotkey 
Sorry, I forgot reply your answer~~ .   
Thank you, I try to refractor my code and it run correctly~ .   
 I’m very grateful for your kind assistance !!

Answer (score 2):

There is a little potential to simplify this.

- Firstly, I would suggest a more functional approach, which could turn the mutable list `rewards` into an immutable one.
- Secondly, infer the creation of the hash-map `reward` with the `put` into one line. You than can use the also the immutable version of the map, instead of the mutable one created by `hashMapOf` (if you need mutability, than you can just keep `hashMapOf`).
- thirdly, you just use the `questionIds` to the the size. For that, you don't have to map anything, just call `examAnswer.ansers.size`. This short call can be inferred as well
- fourthly, you can use `it` instead of explicitly name the param `examAnswer` because this block is now quite short anyway

This would lead to this code:

```
val rewards = rangeExams.map { 
        mapOf("Score" to it.answerScore,
              "NewQuestion" to it.answers.size)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you~Your reply is also grate~~